# Video chat in inappbrowser IONIC 4

Tags: ionic4, hybrid-mobile-app

I am building an application. One feature is to online video call.So my question I have a third party link for a video chat, Can i open that link in inappbroser _blank and start the video chat?

Thanks for the Answer.

Answer (score 0):

As your question description is very short but my understanding says.

NO.

1- _blank will lead to chrome or default browser which is not good at all.
2- If you use inAppBrowser your app might reject an app store and play store as they forced not to use that.

Comment: But can you help me link what i can do to open a video call link and start video chat in ionic app.

Comment: you can do an ionic app it self. 
if I got you right.

Comment: I am not able to open Video call link in inappbrowser as its asking me for permission which i already gave and asking programmatically as well. So its not working for me.